# Django: Serpy serializer django model JsonField

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am using serpy to serialize my model, so my model has a JSONField containing list of dict. Here is my model:

```
class Section(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    item_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    # The JSON field
    contents = models.JSONField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I am trying to use `serpy.DictSerializer` to serialize the `contents` field but it results in empty dict `{}` .

This is my serializer:

```
class SectionSerializer(serpy.Serializer):
    title = serpy.StrField()
    item_count = serpy.IntField()
    data = serpy.MethodField()

    def get_data(self, obj):
        return serpy.DictSerializer(obj.contents, many=True).data
```

As contents is a list of dicts, I have used `many=True`, But still it is not helping.

Answer (score 0):

At last I have solved the problem with the `serpy.Field`

```
    data = serpy.Field(attr="contents")
```